# Internet explorer alignment issues

Tags: css, internet-explorer, web

Yes its the most dreaded issue for all web developers, I'm having issues with I.E, my website currently functions on all browsers aside from ie, the website is http://www.justistuff.com.au/test

The problem is it fails to read the css correctly and it aligns it wrong, is there any way to fix it?

Comment: Remove comments before the doctype.

Comment: LEGEND! However it didn't fix the drop shadow on the icon labels, is there anyway to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Try to reset the default browser styles, using for example [Eric Meyer's css reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

Comment: I have fixed the alignment issue thanks to duri but will this assist in fixing the icon label drop shadow issue?